# List guest machine names from command prompt

Tags: virt-install

How to list the names of all guest machines from the command line using,

```
virt-install
```

Something like, `virt-install list-vms` will do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean `virsh list` which will list all running VMs?

```
# virsh list
 Id    Name                           State
----------------------------------------------------
 2     IPA_DC2                        running
 3     test                           running
```

Or `virsh list --all` which shows running and shutoff VMs?

```
# virsh list --all
 Id    Name                           State
----------------------------------------------------
 2     IPA_DC2                        running
 3     test                           running
 -     Archlinux                      shut off
 -     Buildbox-EL6                   shut off
 -     c5                             shut off
 -     c6                             shut off
 -     c7                             shut off
 -     CentOS7                        shut off
 -     Debian7                        shut off
 -     Fedora-QEMU-A9-armhfp-20-1-sda shut off
 -     fedora20-ppc64                 shut off
 -     FreeSWITCH                     shut off
 -     OpenStack_Juno                 shut off
 -     Puppet                         shut off
 -     Ubuntu1204                     shut off
 -     Windows2008R2                  shut off
 -     Windows2012R2                  shut off
 -     Windows_8_1                    shut off
 -     WindowsXP                      shut off
```

See also `man virsh` for every option.

Or use the `virt-manager` GUI to manage your VMs.

[image: virt-manager GUI]

Comment: You use each tool whenever you want to do whatever the tool does.

Comment: i get the implied message, you intend to give, Michael H... thanks...